# Criteria query returns []

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to use the criteria repository to look for DB records by class fields when some class fields can be null. I am checking strings, integers, and I am using the 'like' in SQL to check bits in a binary word.

Both my entity class and my metamodel are in a separate package :

```
-metapackage
    |
    +-MyEntity1.java
    |
    +-MyEntity1_.java
```

This is my metamodel :

```
    public static volatile SingularAttribute< MyEntity1, String> country;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute< MyEntity1, String> city;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute< MyEntity1, LocalDate> added;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute< MyEntity1, String> address;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute< MyEntity1, UserJPA> userJpa;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute< MyEntity1, String> title;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute< MyEntity1, Integer> size;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute< MyEntity1, String> sizeUnit;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute< MyEntity1, String> flags;// <<<<<<< this is a binary word of 8 bits
    public static volatile SingularAttribute< MyEntity1, Long> id;
```

This is my criteria code :

```
    CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManagerFactory.getCriteriaBuilder();
    
    CriteriaQuery< MyEntity1> cquery = builder.createQuery( MyEntity1.class);
    Root< MyEntity1> croot = cquery.from( MyEntity1.class);
    
    cquery.select(croot);
    Predicate pred = builder.isNotNull(croot.<String>get( MyEntity1_.flags));
    
    if(RestPreconditions.checkString(model.getCity())) {
        pred = builder.and(pred, builder.equal(croot.get( MyEntity1_.city), model.getCity()));
    }
    if(RestPreconditions.checkString(model.getCountry())) {
        pred = builder.and(pred, builder.equal(croot.get( MyEntity1_.country), model.getCountry()));
    }
    if(RestPreconditions.checkString(model.getAddress())) {
        pred = builder.and(pred, builder.equal(croot.get( MyEntity1_.address), model.getAddress()));
    }
    
    if(model.getMaxSize()!=null) {
        pred = builder.and(pred, builder.lessThanOrEqualTo(croot.get( MyEntity1_.size), model.convertSizeToM2(model.getMaxSize())));
    }
    if(model.getMinSize()!=null) {
        pred = builder.and(pred, builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(croot.get( MyEntity1_.size), model.convertSizeToM2(model.getMinSize())));
    }
    // .flagsToBword() always returns something
    String bword = model.flagsToBWord();
    if(!bword.matches("0{8}")){
        pred = builder.and(pred, builder.like(croot.<String>get( MyEntity1_.flags), bword.replaceAll("0", "_")));
    }
    
    return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()
            .createQuery(cquery.where(pred))
            .getResultList();
```

The problem is that I keep getting an **empty list** as the response, even though I know there are objects in the database that match.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT :

For example, if I want to find records in a city named London, this is the object I send :

```
{
    "city":"London"
}
```

I have a database record with that city in a row.

Also, this line of code at the beginning when i construct my predicate :

Predicate pred = builder.isNotNull(croot.get( MyEntity1_.flags));

Is there just to initiate conjunction ; flags is never null

Comment: Could you give a (preferably simple) example object which is in your db and should be returned after executing the query?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. The only mistake that you have made is you override the value of pred every time.

> If you want to chain where statements, you have to reassign pred value with itself + where clause.

```
Specification<MyEntity1> spec = Specification.where(
    (root, cb, cq) -> cb.isNotNull(root.get(MyEntity1_.flags)));

if (RestPreconditions.checkString(model.getCity())) 
    spec = spec.and(
        (root, cb, cq) -> cb.equal(root.get(MyEntity1_.city), model.getCity()))

return yourRepository.findAll(spec);
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out.

When i am calling :

```
String bword = model.flagsToBWord();
```

I would combine the array of flags into a string/binary word by using **java.util.Arrays**

And that would produce a string like :

```
"[0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1]"
```

Instead of a regular binary word that i needed :

```
"00100101"
```

Of course it wasn't working ; it was always looking for a record with invalid LIKE value.

Now it is working properly.